# Getting Ember frontend and Flask backend to communicate through separate Docker containers

Tags: docker, flask, ember.js

I have dockerized a backend webapp built with Flask. The `CMD` line of the `Dockerfile` runs `python app.py` which internally calls `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`, so that the app is running (within the docker container) at `0.0.0.0:5000`. I then run the built container with

```
$ docker run -p 5000:5000 -it my-image:latest
```

The frontend is built with ember. Within the `.ember-cli` file, `proxy` is set to `http://localhost:5000`. When I run `$ ember serve` locally, the app runs smoothly at `localhost:4200`, communicating with the backend running from the docker image. However, I also want to run the frontend on a docker image (based on an apache image). My Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine
COPY ./dist/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY ./.htaccess /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

The `.htaccess` file is copied directly from [Ember - Deploying](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/deploying/) (as per the `Servers` section):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I then do the following:

```
$ ember b --prod  # build the app for production (stored in ./dist/)
$ docker build -t my-frontend:latest .
$ docker run -dit --name my-frontend -p 8080:80 my-frontend:latest
```

I then go to `localhost:8080`, and can see my app's loading wheel, which means this image is working in isolation. However, I continue to get 404 errors when it tries to access the backend.

What am I doing wrong that the containers can't communicate with each other?

Comment: From the Ember container’s point of view, `localhost` is the Ember container.

Comment: @DavidMaze `-p 8080:80` binds the host's port 8080 to the container's port 80. So while the app is being served on the container's `localhost:80` it's being served on my `localhost:8080`. This is my understanding

Comment: what OS are you using? have you tried docker-compose? docker-compose does networking for you

Comment: Right, but the Ember container makes an outbound call to `localhost:5000`, which is to say, port 5000 within the Ember container.  Unless I’m misunderstanding what that proxy setting does.

Comment: you can change the host based on ENV: https://gitlab.com/precognition-llc/aeonvera-ui/blob/master/app/adapters/application.js#L8

Comment: you may need to add a rule to /etc/hosts to alias your docker network name to localhost